# How to insert a light gray line in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'd like to insert a light gray horizontal line to separate my jobs on my resume, like the following (screenshot from Linkedin):

[image]

Do you see the line? How do I insert this line on Microsoft Word. While it's possible to draw a horizontal line on Word, it's too dark and thick.

*Word 2011, Mac OSX*

Comment: change the line's properties

Comment: @jsotola It didn't have that, at least not in my Word version. If your version has it, can you please write an answer with a screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

A horizontal line is simply a paragraph border.

1. Click the design tab
2. Page borders
3. Click the borders tab
4. Change the color, weight
5. Set apply to to paragraph
6. Click the bottom border icon
7. Click OK

[image: Microsoft word horz line]

Answer (score 1):

Go to insert > Shapes and select the line. You can now adjust both the colour, the shape, as well the thickness of the line (by adjusting the weight parameter).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Word is one of these:
Word 2016 Outlook 2016 Word 2013 Outlook 2013 Word 2010 Outlook 2010 Word 2007 Outlook 2007
and you have Auto Correct enabled, you can use the 3 hyphens shortcut:

```
--- <enter>
```

as documented here:

```
https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/insert-or-remove-horizontal-lines-or-rules-9bf172f6-5908-4791-9bb9-2c952197b1a9
```

Comment: But the line is too dark. I am looking for a light line like the one in my screenshot.

Comment: I have this feature, and I did it before I posted the question. It's too dark and thick, not like the one on Linkedin.

Comment: Please edit your original post, adding the Word version you use.

Comment: Word 2011 Mac OSX.